# R: Warning: Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory: Timeout was reached: [www.quandl.com] Connection timed out after 10015 milliseconds

Tags: r, api, quandl

I am facing an issue while importing data from Quandl API in R. I have also tried to use the API key but no matter what i do, everytime i get this same error.

I have tried alphavantage, which works fine. I also tested the Quandl api in python, which also works fine. But i have to use Quandl in R.

Comment: sounds like you are running headlong into a firewall.

Comment: can you tell me how i can avoid that? i tried to fix it myself but its still not working.

Comment: i know too little of your (or your work place's) setup to help much but maybe [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy) will help